# Swift Conditional conformances with Generic Type

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get to work a Swift Extension with two generic types. I tried to make an example.

We have a Box where we can for different types.

```
class Box<E> {
    var value: E
    init(val: E) {
        value = val
    }
}
```

Now we have a special Itemtype which can again have different types

```
class Item<Type> {
    var value: Type
    init(val: Type) {
        value = val
    }
}
```

So now we can easily create an `Box<Item<Int>>`. But maybe we want to change it to `Box<Item<String>>`
So I would like to have an extension to change from `Box<Item<A>>` to `Box<Item<B>>`

What does work is the following

```
extension Box where E: Item<Any> {
    func mapOnItem(function: (Any) -> Any) -> Box<Item<Any>> {
        return Box<Item<Any>>(val: Item(val: function(value.value)))
    }
}
```

But this is not very useful because we don't have the connection from the function return value to the mapOnItem return value.

So I tried to fix but I'm failing. My understanding would be to introduce another generic variable here.

```
extension Box<A> where E: Item<A> {
    func mapOnItem<B>(function: (A) -> B) -> Box<Item<B>> {
        return Box<Item<B>>(val: Item(val: function(value.value)))
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error

> Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic
>   type 'Box' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause

Do you have any clues for me? Is it even possible?

Thanks for your help

Martin

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A constraint on the extension can restrict the placeholder type `E` to concrete types or protocols, for example:

```
extension Box where E: Item<Any> {}
extension Box where E == String {}
extension Box where E: Numeric {}
```

But you cannot put a generic constraint on the extension:

```
extension Box<A> where E: Item<A> {}
// Error: Constrained extension must be declared on the unspecialized generic
// type 'Box' with constraints specified by a 'where' clause
```

The solution is to restrict the *method* instead:

```
extension Box  {
    func mapOnItem<A, B>(function: (A) -> B) -> Box<Item<B>> where E: Item<A> {
        return Box<Item<B>>(val: Item(val: function(self.value.value)))
    }
}
```