# Extending array for object with generic type gives error

Tags: swift, generics

I'm trying this

```
struct Foo<T: Equatable> {
    let object: T
}


extension Array where Element == Foo { // this lines give me error tried Foo<T> but didn't work

    func updateElement(element: Element) {
        // Do the stuff
    }
}
```

And it's giving me error: `Reference to generic type 'Foo' requires arguments in <...>`

Any way to do this?

Comment: Foo<Int> and Foo<String> for instance are two completely different types so that why it doesn't work

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I understand both of them are different, that's why I want to specify Generic there, other wise I have to copy same code in all possible extension (e.g. Int, String, Float, etc.)

Comment: But they _are_ different, Foo<Int> and Foo<String> are as different as Int and String are and that is why you can't just say Foo.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Swift Conditional conformances with Generic Type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55023784/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR thanks it's related and answer to both of them seems same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is to move the constrain from the extension to the method, create a generic `Equatable` type and add a where clause constraining the collection `Element` to `Foo`

```
extension Collection {
    func updateElement<T: Equatable>(element: Element) where Element == Foo<T> {

    }
}
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No you won't be able to mix different types of elements. This will require that all elements in the collection are one or another

Comment: There is no magic solution for this. I would consider a switch there an error of design. It all depends on the goal. I am assuming that OP needs to check them for equality. Anyway all OP might need if it is not the case is a custom protocol or protocol composition.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson  I will use the Equatable protocol to compare stuff, I don't care what kind of object it is. Just want that object to implement Equatable.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson btw it's is not real implementation, was an example. where in `updateElement` i would find it in array and update it. I can't post my original code, it's just easiest example for my scenario. Sorry if my question was not clear

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can only create an extension for a specific type of Foo, like `Foo<Int>`. This works:

```
extension Array where Element == Foo<Int> { // this lines give me error tried Foo<T> but didn't work

    func updateElement(element: Element) {
        // Do the stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I want T  to be generic not Int or String, I updated my question, T is equatable.