# Use a protocol rather than a struct as an (optional array) extension?

Tags: swift, protocols, extension-methods

Say you have

```
struct Screw: Codable {
  let id: String
  ..  more
}
struct Nail: Codable {
  let id: String
  ..  more
}
```

then

```
struct Parts: Codable {
  var Screws: [Screw]?
  var Nails: [Nail]?
}
```

and an extension on the optional array

```
extension Optional {
    mutating func blah() where Wrapped == [Screw] {
        if self == nil { self = [] }
        // we use the .id property ..
        if self!.count > 13 && self![13].id == 666 { self?.remove(at: 13) }
    }
}
```

you can then conveniently

```
stuff.parts.Screws.blah()
```

However if I sensibly

```
protocol IDable {
    var id: Int { get }
}
struct Screw: Codable, IDable { ..
struct Nail: Codable, IDable { ..
```

It seems you can **NOT** do this,

```
extension Optional {
    mutating func blah() where Wrapped == [IDable] { ..
```

Because at compile time

```
stuff.parts.Screws.blah()
```

> Instance method 'blah()' requires the types '[Screw]' and '[any IDable]' be equivalent

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: `IDable` already exists in the standard library - it's called `Identifiable<Int>`. :-)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64895142/5133585) answer your question? It's not exactly the same scenario, but IMO it's relatively straightforward to adapt the solution there. I'll reopen if you still struggle with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encapsulating the solution from the linked question, to this actual situation, the solution is ...

```
mutating func blah() where Wrapped == [Screw] {
```

becomes

```
mutating func blah<T: IDable>() where Wrapped == [T] {
```

or

```
mutating func bleh(item: Screw) where Wrapped == [Screw] {
```

becomes

```
mutating func bleh<T: IDable >(item: T) where Wrapped == [T] {
```